# PureScript equivalent to Haskell’s >> operator

Tags: monads, standard-library, purescript

Is there a PureScript standard library equivalent to Haskell’s `>>` operator?

```
class Monad m where
...
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
...
```

Obviously it’s trivial to define but I would prefer to use a library version if there is one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't actually used Purescript, but from glancing at library documentation it seems the equivalent is called [applySecond](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Control.Apply#v:applySecond), which also has an operator alias `*>`.

(The same operator exists in Haskell, with `(>>)` just being the restricted version that only operates on monads. As far as I can see, Purescript avoids a lot of the redundancy that has arisen in Haskell's typeclass hierarchy for historical reasons.)

Comment: Ah. I saw that but didn’t look further than the name (which didn’t sound like it would do what I wanted). Should’ve looked at the type.. Thanks!

Comment: @Roly to complement this answer I want to point out that it is possible to use type search on Pursuit: https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=+m+a+-%3E+m+b+-%3E+m+b